# Getting poor quality picture in Windows UWP if taken immediately after start

Tags: windows, camera, uwp, c++-cx

Getting poor quality picture in Windows UWP if taken immediately after starting preview. TakePhotoAsync() is called in StartPreviewAsync() task then part. Consistently getting poor quality pictures. How to get good quality picture immediately after starting preview?. Code is based on [CameraStarterKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit).

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the MediaCapture, registers events, gets camera device information for mirroring and rotating, starts preview and unlocks the UI
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    task<void> MainPage::InitializeCameraAsync()
    {
        DBOUT(__func__);
        WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

        // Get available devices for capturing pictures
        return FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::Panel::Back)
            .then([this](DeviceInformation^ camera)
        {
            if (camera == nullptr)
            {
                WriteLine("No camera device found!");
                return;
            }
            // Figure out where the camera is located
            if (camera->EnclosureLocation == nullptr || camera->EnclosureLocation->Panel == Windows::Devices::Enumeration::Panel::Unknown)
            {
                // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                _externalCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Camera is fixed on the device
                _externalCamera = false;

                // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                _mirroringPreview = (camera->EnclosureLocation->Panel == Windows::Devices::Enumeration::Panel::Front);
            }

            _mediaCapture = ref new Capture::MediaCapture();

            // Register for a notification when video recording has reached the maximum time and when something goes wrong
            _recordLimitationExceededEventToken =
                _mediaCapture->RecordLimitationExceeded += ref new Capture::RecordLimitationExceededEventHandler(this, &MainPage::MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded);
            _mediaCaptureFailedEventToken =
                _mediaCapture->Failed += ref new Capture::MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler(this, &MainPage::MediaCapture_Failed);

            auto settings = ref new Capture::MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings->VideoDeviceId = camera->Id;
            settings->StreamingCaptureMode = Capture::StreamingCaptureMode::AudioAndVideo;

            // Initialize media capture and start the preview
            create_task(_mediaCapture->InitializeAsync(settings))
                .then([this]()
            {
                _isInitialized = true;
                return StartPreviewAsync()
                    .then([this]()
                {   
                    UpdateCaptureControls();
                });
            }).then([this](task<void> previousTask)
            {
                try
                {
                    previousTask.get();
                }
                catch (AccessDeniedException^)
                {
                    WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the preview and adjusts it for for rotation and mirroring after making a request to keep the screen on
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    task<void> MainPage::StartPreviewAsync()
    {
        DBOUT(__func__);
        // Prevent the device from sleeping while the preview is running
        _displayRequest->RequestActive();

        // Set the preview source in the UI and mirror it if necessary
        PreviewControl->Source = _mediaCapture.Get();
        PreviewControl->FlowDirection = _mirroringPreview ? Windows::UI::Xaml::FlowDirection::RightToLeft : Windows::UI::Xaml::FlowDirection::LeftToRight;

        // Start the preview
        return create_task(_mediaCapture->StartPreviewAsync())
            .then([this](task<void> previousTask)
        {
            _isPreviewing = true;

            FN_TRACE("CameraStreamState::Streaming %d\n", _mediaCapture->CameraStreamState);
            TakePhotoAsync();
            // Only need to update the orientation if the camera is mounted on the device
            if (!_externalCamera)
            {
                return SetPreviewRotationAsync();
            }

            // Not external, just return the previous task
            return previousTask;
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a photo to a StorageFile and adds rotation metadata to it
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    task<void> MainPage::TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        DBOUT(__func__);
        // While taking a photo, keep the video button enabled only if the camera supports simultaneously taking pictures and recording video
        VideoButton->IsEnabled = _mediaCapture->MediaCaptureSettings->ConcurrentRecordAndPhotoSupported;
        // Make the button invisible if it's disabled, so it's obvious it cannot be interacted with
        VideoButton->Opacity = VideoButton->IsEnabled ? 1 : 0;

        auto inputStream = ref new Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        // Take the picture
        WriteLine("Taking photo...");
        return create_task(_mediaCapture->CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(Windows::Media::MediaProperties::ImageEncodingProperties::CreateJpeg(), inputStream))
            .then([this, inputStream]()
        {
            return create_task(_captureFolder->CreateFileAsync("SimplePhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName));
        }).then([this, inputStream](StorageFile^ file)
        {
            WriteLine("Photo taken! Saving to " + file->Path);

            // Done taking a photo, so re-enable the button
            VideoButton->IsEnabled = true;
            VideoButton->Opacity = 1;

            auto photoOrientation = ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(GetCameraOrientation());
            return ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(inputStream, file, photoOrientation);
        }).then([this](task<void> previousTask)
        {
            try
            {
                previousTask.get();
            }
            catch (Exception^ ex)
            {
                // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
                WriteException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'd think this is rather normal. Camera always need some time to set focus and do some other stuff. So we need to preview first and then take the photo.

Comment: Is there any event handler available to notify that camera is ready to take pictures after starting preview?